# Not able to add + in fileeditor Yii extension

Tags: javascript, yii, wysiwyg, yii-extensions

I am using fileeditor Yii extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/fileeditor 
When I am saving file using this file editor, it's working pretty fine except one case. It's removing + symbol from file contents.

Like, I am adding 
`{$rownum = $rownum + 1}` in file. After saving, it's replacing this line with

```
{$rownum = $rownum   1}
```

I don't know why it's happening, but somehow I am not able to find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the controller **FileeditorController.php** at action **actionPutContent**.

Change line:

```
echo file_put_contents($file, urldecode ($_POST['filecontent']));
```

to

```
echo file_put_contents($file, $_POST['filecontent']);
```

Using "**urldecode**" on filecontent parameter does not make sense. The parameter is not url encoded when sent.